# Proper way to define functions with domain (arrow syntax)

Tags: equations

I'd like to define my functions using the "arrow syntax", to also define the domain (I can't remember if the canonical notation uses braces or not):

[image]

however to produce this drawing I needed to use `cases` and manually adding spacing with `\,\,\,` which is a bit dirty I think. Otherwise, I get this, which looks not very nice in my opinion.

[image]

What is the proper way to define this in LaTeX?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\begin{document}
\[
    f(x) \colon
\begin{cases}
  \mathbb{N} & \longrightarrow\,\,\, \mathbb{N} \\
  x          & \longmapsto\,\,\, x^2
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you have to add this spacing?

Comment: @Bernard Otherwise I think the result is not good looking, as the space before and after the arrow is not identical. See my edit.

Answer (score 7):

I would not use the `cases` environment, which, semantically, is meaningless here. I would use a simple `align` environment, like this;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f\colon \mathbf N & \longrightarrow\mathbf N \\[-1ex]
  x & \longmapsto x^2
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking there would exists something just for that (I'm not sure the semantic of align is better than cases ^^) Also, the problem of this solution is that if N is too large, like $\{0,1\} \times A \times B \times C$, then the alignment of the $x$ is done to the right instead of to the left, which gives a pretty bad style. I used instead an `\begin{alignat}{4}...` with one `&` to align after the colon, and the double `&&` before the arrows, the result is better looking I think.

Comment: It's another possibility, but you have to choose the spacing between consecutive alignment columns.

Comment: B.t. w, in the case of a larger domain; I think the alihnment has to be on the right, to keep a uniform spacing from the beginning of the `mapsto` symbol.

Comment: I'm not sure to see what you mean. Also, I'm thinking of another issue: if you want to number this equation, you also need to put a `\nonumber` on one line. And I guess you can't put this number in between these equations with `align` or `alignat` (which you would likely want to have since technically speaking this is the same equation).

Comment: Not necessarily: you just have to nest an `aligned`  environment in  `equation`.

Answer (score 5):

As suplement to @Bernard answer (+1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
f\colon \left\{\begin{aligned}
                \mathbf N & \longrightarrow\mathbf N \\
                x & \longmapsto x^2
               \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility it is to use `tikz-cd` package as the image below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-4pt, column sep= normal]
 f\colon\!  \mathbb{N} \arrow[r] & \mathbb{N} \\
\quad x \arrow[r, maps to] & x^2       
\end{tikzcd}$

\end{document}
```

You can decrease the leght of the arrow putting a value in pt in column sep instead of normal. See this example with `column sep= 10pt`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

$\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=-4pt,column sep= 10pt]
f\colon \mathbb{N} \arrow[r] & \mathbb{N} \\[-1pt]
\quad x \arrow[r, maps to] & x^2       
\end{tikzcd}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I find the arrows a bit long, but I guess it's a matter of taste ^^

Comment: @tobiasBora ahaha :-)...but you can decrease the size of the lenght of the arrow: see the comment at the end of my answer. Now I done an edit.

Answer (score 3):

I've never seen the notation with the braces; anyway, the “(*x*)” next to *f* is (mathematically) out of place.

If you want the brace, with no additional space that would result from `aligned` or `cases`, you can use an `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\function}[5]{%
  #1\colon
  \left\lbrace
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
  #2 & \rightarrow & #3 \\
  #4 & \mapsto     & #5
  \end{array}%
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
}
\newcommand{\longfunction}[5]{%
  #1\colon
  \left\lbrace
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} l }
  #2 & \longrightarrow & #3 \\
  #4 & \longmapsto     & #5
  \end{array}%
  \right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
}

\begin{document}

This is a function
\[
\function{f}{\mathbb{N}}{\mathbb{N}}{x}{x^2}
\]
And now we compare it with Zarko's proposal
\[
f\colon \left\{\begin{aligned}
                \mathbf N & \longrightarrow\mathbf N \\
                x & \longmapsto x^2
               \end{aligned}\right.
\]
and yours
\[
    f \colon
\begin{cases}
  \mathbb{N} & \longrightarrow\,\,\, \mathbb{N} \\
  x          & \longmapsto\,\,\, x^2
\end{cases}
\]
Finally, the ``long'' version
\[
\longfunction{f}{\mathbb{N}}{\mathbb{N}}{x}{x^2}
\]

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer the “short” version, but that's up to your preference. Note that the two instance in the center are not really centered.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I like this approach also because it allows me to center the text (I think it looks nicer when the set is quite large). Also, do you mean you never seen the brace symbol in this notation, or that you never say this notation at all? I also tried to remove the brace to have a version with and without brace, and align the $f$ on the first line by putting `|t]` in the array, but then the number of the equation (when using align) is put on the first line instead of in-between. Also, you don't need to add a group around the newcommand to avoid changing the `\arraycolsep` everywhere?

Comment: (and if I try to put the f in the array directly, the spacing looks bad)